# Grouping related fields together

Tags: entry, admin

Is there a mechanism for grouping related fields in an entry besides:

- a) putting them in a tab - which I generally reserve to group fields at a higher order (e.g content/data/meta)
- b) putting related fields inside a matrix block with a limit of 1, which feels like I'm adding a level of complexity to my content model.

I have various modules in a page, so i've taken to labelling them with a common prefix for each module (as in 'Homepage Hero - Background Image', 'Homepage Hero - Subheading'), but all of the fields visually gel together in the UI in a somewhat indistinguishable list.

I suppose changing my use of tabs would serve my purpose, but could look quite unruly on an entry with many elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in a supertable which supports nested matrix etc.
All the info on supertable here: https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable

Comment: I'm not sure that offers any improvement over putting them in a matrix field, and there would then be an extra third-party dependency.

Comment: Since he said "but all of the fields visually gel together in the UI in a somewhat indistinguishable list." my answer is quiet relevant. The supertable has the "row" option which gives a clear difference from a matrix. in layout.